# Evaluate the integral $\int_{7}^{19} \sqrt{(x-7)(19-x)}dx$

Tags: calculus

> Evaluate the integral $$\int_{7}^{19} \sqrt{(x-7)(19-x)}dx$$

Now so far most radical integrals I've dealt with are a simpler but I have to use trigonometric substitution generally so this is what I tried so far to make it look like something I can use trigonometric substitution.

$$\sqrt{-x^2+26x-133}$$

$$=\sqrt{36-(x-13)^2}$$
$$=\sqrt{6^2-(x-13)^2}$$

Now this is kind of similar to the form I'm used to which is

$$\sqrt{a^2-b^2x^2} \implies x=\frac{a}{b}\sin\theta$$

Though not quite so I'm probably missing something obvious now but I'm a little stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: You also accordingly change the limits of integration

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hint.** Your integral is the area of the half-disc with the diameter $19-7 =12$.

Comment: Great answer +1

Comment: Oh so I have $(x-13)^2+y^2=36$ which is a semi circle centered at $(13,0)$ with radius $=6$ therefore the area is just $\frac{1}{2}\pi36=18\pi$

Comment: @HighSchool15, Exactly! Of course, if we are integrating over different region, then you may want to use some trigonometric substitution. Even in such cases you will need to complete the square inside the square root. Shailesh, Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

For $(x-a)(b-x)$ with  $b\ge x\ge a$ in the radical, try with

$$x=a\cos^2y+b\sin^2y$$

Answer (score 1):

Notice, $(x-7)(19-x)=26x-x^2-133=6^2-(x-13)^2$ Hence, we get $$\int_{7}^{19}\sqrt{(x-7)(19-x)}dx=\int_{7}^{19}\sqrt{6^2-(x-13)^2}dx$$ Let, $x-13=t\implies dx=dt$ $$=\int_{-6}^{6}\sqrt{6^2-t^2}dt$$
$$=2\int_{0}^{6}\sqrt{6^2-t^2}dt$$
$$=2\cdot \frac{1}{2}\left[t\sqrt{6^2-t^2}+36\sin^{-1}\left(\frac{t}{6}\right)\right]_{0}^{6}$$
$$=\left[0+36\sin^{-1}\left(1\right)-0\right]$$ $$=36\cdot \frac{\pi}{2}=18\pi$$

$$\bbox[5px, border:2px solid #C0A000]{\color{red}{\int_{7}^{19}\sqrt{(x-7)(19-x)}dx=18\pi}}$$

Comment: Could someone please explain the reason for what is wrong in the answer?